# Call stack in java

Tags: java, akka

In Akka documentation, there was a part talked about **"The illusion of a call stack"**, um attaching a picture for a part of it. I don't get what he is talking about, I mean if the main thread in java created a new thread and start it if any exception thrown in the created thread the main thread will be notified, so why he is saying that the "caller" will not be notified?!

[image: The illusion of a call stack]

Comment: "if the main thread in java created a new thread and start it if any exception thrown in the created thread the main thread will be notified" - No, if an exception occurs in a different thread, the main thread is not automatically notified.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with concurrent programming in general, and in fact call stacks address concurrent programming rather well, thanks to the interesting insight that recursion and multi-threading both require nothing more complex than re-entrancy, which a call stack provides. It has do with *asynchronous* programming only, and as you say Java already solves the issues raised, although via the unc aught exception handler, not by propagating exception to the main thread, which doesn't  actually exist in Java.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean if the main thread in java created a new thread and start it if any exception thrown in the created thread the main thread will be notified

That is false. Unless the main thread explicitly sets up an uncaught exception handler, it will not be notified of any exceptions in thread it launches (and the uncaught exception handler will also not run in the main thread, so technically the main thread isn't notified at all).

The "illusion of a call stack" is about the fact that the *conceptual* flow of logic no longer fits the physical call stack when you use things like work queues to schedule separate tasks on other threads.

The actual call stack of any failing sub-task on such a queue will show code related to handling the *queue* but will not show the calls stack related to the code that *initially queued the task* which is arguably the more interesting one in many cases.